# How to log to file per task if execution is within a Celery task context

Tags: python, logging, celery

I want to modify my current logging setup without having to pass logger objects into functions as a parameter. Currently at the top of each module I define a LOG object

```
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I want to change the logging so that:

- the logs log to file, but only if the execution context is within a Celery task
- there is a file per task
- without having to modify the code of each task

Thus if you have two tasks:

```
@task
def taskOne():
  LOG.log("in task one")
  foo.foo()

@task
def taskTwo():
  LOG.log("in task two")
  foo.foo
```

and in module foo:

```
def foo():
  LOG.log("in foo")
```

Then:

- executing `taskOne` should send "in task one\nin foo" into a file named "taskOne.log"
- executing `taskTwo` should send "in task two\nin foo" into a file named "taskTwo.log"
- executing `foo` outside of a celery task should not send logs to a file

I'm thinking of coming up with a handler that inspects the call stack to see if it is currently executing in the context of a celery task, and if so, log to a file. However I'm not sure whether the solution would be performant, or whether it's implementing bad practice.